# Sum values in xmlstarlet from two siblings?

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I am using `xmlstarlet` to extract text from elements with a specific preceding sibling event. An example from the XML file:

```xml
 <event type='cue' units='sec'>
    <onset>11.134</onset>
    <duration>0.2</duration>
    <value name='side'>CUER</value>
  </event>
  <event type='target' units='sec'>
    <onset>11.367</onset>
    <duration>1.26</duration>
    <value name='side'>TARGETR</value>
    <value name='RT' units='msec'>379</value>
    <value name='TargCorr'>1</value>
    <value name='feedback'>YOU WIN!</value>
  </event>
  <event type='anticipation' units='sec'>
    <onset>12.651</onset>
    <duration>2.65</duration>
    <value name='TargCorr'>1</value>
    <value name='feedback'>YOU WIN!</value>
  </event>
```

From the example, I need to do the following:

1. print the `onset` of `<event type='target'`, and
2. print the sum of the `duration` of the `<event type='target'` and immediately following `duration` of the `<event type='anticipation'`.

I can print the correct `onset` using the `"preceding-sibling"` option:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t \
 -m '//event[@type="anticipation" and value[@name="feedback"]="YOU WIN!"]' \
 -m 'preceding-sibling::event[@type="target" and value[@name="feedback"]="YOU WIN!"][1] ' \
 -v 'onset' -o ' ' -v 'duration' -o ' ' -o '1' -n $DIR/$xml \
   > $DIR/output.stf
```

Though as written, the following code only displays the duration from the matched element rather than summing the duration of the two adjacent events. **Is the latter possible using xmlstarlet?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: +1 for having even attempted to process XML with an XML parser. You're a step ahead of most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering without looking too closely at the *code* that you provide since it does not correspond with the description that precedes it.

Assuming you want to retrieve the `onset` value for each `event` node with a `type` attribute with the value `target`, you can do that using `xmlstarlet` with

```bash
xmlstarlet select --template \
    --value-of '//event[@type = "target"]/onset' \
    -nl file
```

Another way to write that is by matching the wanted set of nodes and extracting the `onset` value from each in turn.  This, in effect, introduces a way of doing multiple operations on a single node before moving on to the next matched node.

```bash
xmlstarlet select --template \
    --match '//event[@type = "target"]' \
    --value-of 'onset' \
    -nl file
```

The "following sibling node" is had with the `following-sibling` selector, and we get the first of the subsequent `event` siblings with a `type` attribute with the value `anticipation` using `following-sibling::event[@type = "anticipation"][1]`.

Adding up the `duration` values of the matched node and its sibling node is done with `sum()`, and we combine that with the command above like so:

```bash
xmlstarlet select --template \
    --match '//event[@type = "target"]' \
    --value-of 'onset' --output ' ' \
    --value-of 'sum(duration | following-sibling::event[@type = "anticipation"][1]/duration)' \
    -nl file
```

Or, using short options,

```bash
xmlstarlet select -t \
    -m '//event[@type = "target"]' \
    -v 'onset' -o ' ' \
    -v 'sum(duration | following-sibling::event[@type = "anticipation"][1]/duration)' \
    -n file
```

Note the syntax for creating a node-set for the `sum()` function. The set of nodes that will be summed matches either of the `|`-delimited XPath queries.

Given the example data in the question, with some encapsulating root node added, this would output

```
11.367 3.91
```

... where the first number is the `onset` number from the `target` node, and the second is the sum of the `duration` values of the `target` node and the associated sibling `anticipation` node.

Comment: Done! Quick addition to the above answer: I added a `[1]` after `following-sibling::event[@type = "anticipation"]` to limit the depth as it was summing all following `anticipation` nodes in the full XML file. Thanks again!

Comment: @XMLnewbie Ah, that's a good addition. I only had your short example document to test with, so I didn't catch that issue. I will update (EDIT: have updated) my answer with this. Thanks!